# MonoTouch.Dialog events and Sections

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, monotouch.dialog

i need one more help.

First question is: I understood that the sections, text, images, etc on a MonoTouch.Dialog will be created dynamically. But can i have buttons as well? If yes, how can i have the events of that button binded.

Second question is : Basically i have a search text, and a button, on the click of the button, the text is sent to the Twitter-url, to get the tweets, these tweets need to be displayed, now they contain, images, texts, and reply and a favourite. Can the search result and the Search Button+Edit box, be the part of one ViewController?

Comment: Please read stackoverflow FAQ it will help you out getting faster/better answers. E.g. you should ask one question per entry since it makes it hard to accept partial answers, which in turns makes it impossible for people to reuse the knowledge in the future (e.g. searching via stackoverflow or google).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But can i have buttons as well?

`Element` in the `DialogViewController` often act like buttons. But if you want a *real* UIButton you can do something like: [Monotouch.Dialog two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296548/monotouch-dialog-two-tables)

> Can the search result and the Search Button+Edit box, be the part of one ViewController?

I don't see any problem doing that. Use the code from the above link and add a `EntryElement`.

> the text is sent to the Twitter-url, to get the tweets, these tweets need to be displayed

Have you looked at **[TweetStation](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TweetStation)** ? It's an open source application that is based on MonoTouch.Dialog. It can likely help you answer questions on both fronts.

Comment: Again...POPOU thanks for the support. You are a great rescue :)

Comment: @AbhishekSharma when you're satisfied with an answer you should mark it as "completed" (green arrow below the votes #). That way other people searching for the same/similar questions will be able to see a solution is available.